# Как скопировать содержимое папки с заданным расширением в другую папку сохраняя исходную структуру каталога в linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, консоль

Как в Ubuntu скопировать файлы только определенного расширения, в другую папку сохраняя при этом структуру исходной папки? Ну например, есть папка корневая, у неё три подпапки, и там есть файлы разного расширения. Мне нужно чтобы все содержимое корневой папки вместе с тремя подпапками ии их содержимым скопировались в другую папку, но только файлы с заданным расширением. 
Типа:

```
Папка1
|
|
Файл1.h
Файл2.cpp
Папка2
   |
   |
   Файл1.h
   Файл2.cpp
```

После команды
должно быть:

```
Папка1
|
|
Файл1.h
Папка2
   |
   |
   Файл1.h
```

т.е. в новую папку скопировалось все содержимое старой папки только с расширением `.h` при этом структура каталога сохранилась. Содержимое подпапок тоже скопировалось, только то что имеет расширение `.h`
Это аналог команды `mac`:

```
gcp --parents
```

Comment: rsync, возможно, сделает то, что вам нужно. Почитайте мануал.

Comment: `gcp` -- GNU `cp`?  И что вас останавливает запустить `cp --parents ...`?

Comment: У вас в вопросе не соответствует пример и требование - похоже на перемещение из `Папка1` или удаление

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tree dir1 -A
dir1
├── dir2
│   ├── dir3
│   │   ├── f1.cpp
│   │   └── f2.h
│   ├── f1.cpp
│   └── f2.h
├── f1.cpp
└── f2.h

2 directories, 6 files
```

```
$ for d in $(find ./dir1 -type d -printf "%p\n"); do [ -e $d ] &&  mkdir -p new_dir/$d; cp $d/*.h new_dir/$d/;  done
```

```
$ tree new_dir/ -A
new_dir/                         
└── dir1
    ├── dir2
    │   ├── dir3
    │   │   └── f2.h
    │   └── f2.h
    └── f2.h

3 directories, 3 files
```

Можно воспользоваться `cp --parents`

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83593/copy-specific-file-type-keeping-the-folder-structure